# Ist „Mittagessen haben“ richtig?

Tags: grammar, usage

Normalerweise sagen wir

> Ich esse um 12 zu Mittag.

Ist es richtig

> Am Mittag hat er Mittagessen.

zu sagen?

Ist

> Um 12 hat er Mitttagesssen.

auch richtig?

Comment: It sounds like a translation from English to have lunch.  But in German this expression is not usual.

Answer (score 10):

Doch, man kann auf Deutsch *Mittagessen haben* sagen, **aber** es hat dann eine andere Bedeutung - es wird als terminliche Verpflichtung (oder zumindest Planung) verstanden.

> Er hat um 12 Uhr Mittagessen

wird entsprechend verstanden als Quasi-Kurzform von

> Er hat um 12 Uhr einen Termin zum Mittagessen
>
> Für 12 Uhr hat er Mittagessen geplant

Das *hat* ist in diesem Satz ein *futurisches Präsens*.

Weiteres Beispiel:

> "Kommst du morgen mit ins Freibad?" - "Geht leider nicht, da habe ich Musikunterricht."

Comment: "Er hat um 12 Uhr Mittagessen" entspricht nicht wirklich "Er hat um 12 Uhr einen Termin zum Mittagessen". Es bedeutet eher, dass er immer um 12 Uhr zu Mittag isst. "Er hat um 12 Uhr *ein* Mittagessen" klingt find ich nach  einem Termin.

Comment: @idmean Guter Einwurf, ich glaube da treffen wir uns in der Mitte. Sowohl die Version mit als auch ohne Artikel beschreiben eine terminliche Verpflichtung. WIrd der Artikel wie in meinem Beispiel weggelassen deutet es in dem allermeisten Fällen auf einen *regelmäßigen* Termin hin (Unterricht, wöchentliche Sportgruppe, etc.). Ausnahmen gibt es aber natürlcih auch; die habe ich z.B. im Kontext von Zeitplänen/Veranstaltungsplänen gefunden: "Um 9:30 ist Frühstück, danach haben wir die erste Theorie-Sitzung, um 12:00 haben wir Mittag, danach ist der erste Praxisteil an der Reihe..."

Comment: "um 12:00 haben wir Mittag" ist dann aber schon sehr stark umgangssprachlich. Aber im Kontext ist natürlich klar was gemeint ist, auch wenn es nicht gerade schönes Deutsch ist.

Comment: richtig, diese Formulierung ist explizit gesprochen-sprachlich; auf einem Zeitplan würde es so nicht stehen, wenn ein Gruppenleiter den Plan kurz mit der Gruppe durchgeht, wäre es absolut ok (gestern erst wieder live erlebt). Anderes Beispiel wären Öffnungszeiten. Auf dem Schild an der Tür steht "Von 11:30 - 12:45 Mittagspause", am Telefon würde man eher gesagt bekommen "von halb zwölf bis viertel vor eins haben/machen wir mittag" (regionale Varianzen). Außer es ist ne automatische Ansage, die orientieren sich ja eher am Schriftsprachlichen.

Answer (score 4):

Nein, das kann man so auf Deutsch nicht sagen. Wenn man Essen „hat“, dann bedeutet das im Deutschen immer, dass man es im weitesten Sinne besitzt. Beispiele für die richtige Verwendung von „Essen haben“ in den <s>seltenen</s> Fällen, in denen es tatsächlich Sinn ergibt:

> Um 10 Uhr habe ich eine Sitzung und um 12 Uhr Mittagessen mit den Kollegen. Wegen meiner Fastenkur esse ich zwar zurzeit nichts, aber es ist trotzdem wichtig, dass ich hingehe. (Mittagessen als Termin.) [Nachtrag nach der Antwort von Konadi]
>
> Ich habe um 12 Uhr nie Mittagessen, denn spätestens um 11:30 bekomme ich Hunger und esse alles auf. Um 12 Uhr ist dann nichts mehr übrig. Allerdings bringe ich mir manchmal auch ein Abendessen mit. Das habe ich um 12 Uhr natürlich noch. Dann habe ich also um 12 Uhr Abendessen, aber kein Mittagessen (Mittagessen im physikalischen Sinn).
>
> Tut mir leid, wir haben kein Mittagessen. Aber kommen Sie doch gerne heute Abend wieder. Dann kann ich Ihnen ein sehr gutes Abendessen anbieten! (Mittagessen als gastronomisches Angebot.)

Im Englischen bedeutet *have lunch*, dass man das Essen isst. Eigentlich ist das etwas unlogisch, denn indem man das Essen isst, bewirkt man ja gerade, dass man es nicht mehr besitzt. Hintergrund dieses Unterschieds ist, dass das Wort *haben* sich vom Vollverb, das Besitz ausdrückt, immer weiter in Richtung eines vielfältig verwendbaren Hilfsverbs entwickelt, das mit Besitz nichts mehr zu tun hat. Im Englischen ist diese Entwicklung schon weiter fortgeschritten als im Deutschen. Im Spanischen ist die Entwicklung schon abgeschlossen, so dass ein anderes Verb (*tener*, ursprüngliche Bedeutung *halten*) an die Stelle von *haber* in seinem ursprünglichen Sinn getreten ist. (Allerdings entwickelt sich jetzt in manchen spanischen Dialekten auch *tener* schon zu einem Hilfsverb!)

Comment: "dann bedeutet das im Deutschen immer, dass man es besitzt" - genau dazu passt aber gleich das erste Beispiel dann nicht. Da wäre die Erklärung eher, dass man das Essen in seinem Terminplan bzw. auf seiner Aufgabenliste hat.

Comment: *Besitzen* ist mein Versuch, von den zwei Bedeutungen von *haben* diejenige herauszupicken, die nicht das Hilfsverb ist. Das ist wohl durch den Kontext nicht so klar geworden, wie ich angenommen habe. Ich werde mal ein "im weitesten Sinne" hinzufügen.

Comment: Der Zweite Satz: "Wenn man Essen ›hat‹, dann bedeutet das im Deutschen immer, dass man es im weitesten Sinne besitzt." ist schlicht falsch.

Comment: @rhavin: Dann würde ich aber gerne ein Gegenbeispiel sehen. Alles, was mir bisher eingefallen ist, passt zur Grundbedeutung von *haben*, solange man *Mittagessen* korrekt als *Mittagessens-Termin*, *Mittagessens-Angebot* usw. interpretiert. Mit *besitzen* im weitesten Sinne meine ich die Grundbedeutung von *haben* als Vollverb im Gegensatz zu den diversen Sonderbedeutungen als Voll- und Hilfsverb, die das Verb auch noch hat - im Deutschen, aber vor allem auch im Englischen, das die ursprüngliche Frage wohl motiviert hat.

Answer (score 0):

Nein. Höchstens mundartlich. Korrekt ist

> "Das Mittagessen einnehmen".

Es kommt allerdings häufiger vor, dass Muttersprachler sagen

> "ich hatte Kalbsbraten zum Mittagessen".

Dieser Satz wird als richtig empfunden, obwohl ich die Formulierung

> "ich aß Kalbsbraten zu Mittag"

vorziehe.

In der Schriftsprache kann "ich habe Mittagessen" selbst in Bezug auf Vereinbarungen nicht gebraucht werden.